# Tensorflow Projected Gradient Descent with Box Constraints using native Optimizer's apply_gradients

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

Say that our model parameters **w** have box constraints (e.g. 0 < w_i < 1).
How can I implement projected gradient descent in Tensorflow respecting this constraints when I optimize using a subclass from tf.optimizer (e.g.ADAMOptimizer)?

Comment: Did you had a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/constrained_optimization ? especially ConstrainedMinimizationProblem and ConstrainedOptimizer ?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In my problem I have access to gradients, but cannot directly pass the likelihood(cost) function for maximization(minimization). I'd like to enforce the constraints at the apply_gradients function of the optimizer.

Comment: Your gradients comes from the unconstrained problem ?

Comment: yes, I compute stochastic gradients of my likelihood which I pass to my optimizer. At each step of the optimizer (I use Adam) I have to keep my model parameters between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

In [tf.get_variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) there is a constraint parameter, I guess you can use it to do your box constraints on the weights variable, using  [tf.clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value) as projection function.

> constraint: An optional projection function to be applied to the variable after being updated by an Optimizer (e.g. used to implement norm constraints or value constraints for layer weights). The function must take as input the unprojected Tensor representing the value of the variable and return the Tensor for the projected value (which must have the same shape). Constraints are not safe to use when doing asynchronous distributed training.